# php foreach - try catch, I don't know why I get 500 Error. I have call activeMQ

Tags: php, foreach

php foreach - try catch, I don't know why I get 500 Error.

in my code, I used this way to call activeMQ, but I will get 500 Error. I don't know what's happen.

This code only run to `$url = "tcp://".$url;`  cannot run to uder `try{}`. Where is issues?

```
$stomp = null;
$mqUser='aaa';
$mqPasswd='aaa';

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $url = "tcp://".$url;
    //echo $url." stomp status: null;<br />";
    try {
        $stomp = new Stomp($url);
    } catch(Exception $e) {

    }
    if ($stomp) {
        break;        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Any clues in the server error log?

Comment: @PaulT. I had checked the log. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Stomp" not found in, so I need to install Stomp in my computer?

Comment: Yes, sounds like that is definitely needed. I don't know Stomp, or what it is, so my help is limited to that end.